# Using a concatenated string in Google sheets query WHERE condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the result of a concatenation of a string and cell contents in a query, but the query function does not seem to like it: see this example

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CtPFLhpD3KDHrk-6WoHft4JdMTVa3OcvHHqAidMWwdM/edit?usp=sharing

The strings in cells B2 and B3 appear to be the same, but whilst C3 gives the desired result, C2 does not.  B3 simply extracts a string from A3, whereas B2 tags the 'E' on in the formula.  The data in the real spreadsheet I am working with is like that in B2, so I have to add the 'E' into the result.  The real list of error codes is quite long and varied, so I cannot edit that to just use the number.  I also tried using CONCATENATE, but that made no difference.

How do I get the query to recognise the contents of C2 as the string 'E151'?

Comment: `="E"&mid(A2,30,4)` is returning `E151 ` (with a space at the end). `=query(A7:B10,"select B where A = '"&trim(B2)&"'",0)` will trim out the space, and give you the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some great answers to my question, thanks!  It was a trailing space causing the problem.

I have combined some of the ideas in the other answers in the real spreadsheet and used

`="E" & trim(mid(A2,30,3))`

Since some of the error codes are only 2 characters long

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's an trailing space in the result of B2.
See if this helps

```
=query(A7:B10,"select B where A = '"&trim(B2)&"'",0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In B2

```
="E"&mid(A2,30,3)
```

or

```
="E"&index(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(\d+)","($1)")),1,5)
```

(the 5th number in the string)

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in column C and use this in C2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(B2:B4), A7:B11, 2, 0)))
```

[image]